# Can I sell a template that uses the fonts on my computer?

Tags: fonts, typefaces, font-licensing

I'm selling templates online and I was wondering if I could use the typefaces I already have on my computer (Mac) or the ones that come with Adobe CC?
Thanks in advance,
Julien

Answer (score 1):

You can **use** the fonts in a template. You **can not** give away **font files**.

What that means is anyone who opens the template and does *not* have the font will get a "missing font" warning or the font won't display correctly.

Almost every commercial font license prohibits the sharing, selling, or otherwise distributing the files associates with the font itself.

Comment: Many templates that I have used in the past get around this issue by using a font that is available for free downloading. The template instructions will include the URL where the end user can download those fonts.

Comment: Thanks Scott, that's a good point! So would it be correct to say that I can sell any digital product that uses the typeface Helvetica for instance WITHOUT providing the fonts themselves?